# how to get total number of reviews from google reviews

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

With the google places api, it is possible to get details related to user reviews of a place.  Looking at the documentation and it seems that I can get the following details:

- rating: 0-5 based on user rates and this is the average of all submitted reviews
- last 5 user ratings

However, there doesn't seem to be any reference to

- total number of reviews
- count total for each rating ie, 5/5: 5 reviews, 4/5: 23 reviews, ...

Anyone have an idea on where to get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new, yet to be documented, details result key `user_ratings_total`.  I believe this is the number of ratings that have contributed to the overall `rating`.

I don't believe the API currently provides count totals for each rating value.  You could request this enhancement (if it hasn't been already) at [gmaps-api-issues](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?q=apitype=PlacesAPI).

Comment: Here's a link to the feature request to display the total number of reviews. The more votes it gets, the more likely they will add it. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5650&q=apitype%3DPlacesAPI&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&start=100

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? How can we fetch the total number of reviews?

Comment: Does `user_ratings_total` not provide what you're looking for?

Comment: yes, it is same as review count display in google+ review summary section. I have tested it for around 200 properties and it gives correct result. But not sure that review count and user_ratings_total is same.

Comment: `user_ratings_total` appears to be removed

Comment: And seems that Google is not interested in get it back :(

Answer (score 3):

it is possible now to get total number of reviews using `Place Details` Place APIs call: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#fields

as of Jan 2019, it returns `user_ratings_total` field: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#335