# google maps API for a place how many people have made reviews and rating?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I made a app and I use goole maps API. I would like know, you know when you make a request for place, API return 5 last reviews and reviews.rating, and rating, for how many reviews this rating is calculate ? How I can have this information do you know?

I calculated for 5 last reviews and rating, the average does not correspond in 5 reviews.rating. Thus how to know this average is calculated on how much reviews?
 Thanks

[image: API return for place]

Edit : in this question (4 years ago) : [how to get total number of reviews from google reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941648/how-to-get-total-number-of-reviews-from-google-reviews?rq=1) I have try this solution **user_ratings_total** but that don't work

Edit 2 : it's certainly possible nobody's know ?

[image: yellow number]

Comment: I think it's not possible for now : user_ratings_total appears to be removed

Comment: The feature request is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820858

Comment: @xomena Yes I have seen that, this request was created in 2011 we are 2018. I think Google don't care

Answer (score 2):

it is possible now to get total number of reviews using `Place Details` Place APIs call: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#fields

as of Jan 2019, it returns `user_ratings_total` field: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#335

which contains the total number of reviews.

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't a long term project, give my API a shot:

http://reviewsmaker.com/api/google/?business=mumbai%20cafe&api_key=4a2819f3-2874-4eee-9c46-baa7fa17971c

You can just swap the business name; I created it local to the US though by the looks of your images it seems you're looking to do it for CA; user_ratings_total was indeed removed from places but the GMB API still has access to this data, I just kind of tweaked it a little bit.

Here's a tip on how you can get the data, if you create a custom RSS feed with the URLs for the places and (not sure what language your using) you can parse through the URLs and get the metadata out; or if you use Google CSE (Custom Search Engine) the PageMap for the schemas 'review', 'aggregatedreviews' will be easy to parse through as well. These are just clevar workarounds; it sucks they omit this data from the natural official API it was very useful.